# bootstrap table and form not visible in php

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get some data from a database and show them in a bootstrap table in php. but the php file only shows navigation bar. it does not show the table or the form. I have checked the connection which is fine. even if connection was wrong it should at least show the table headers and form labels. which it does not.

```
<?php 
include 'adminlogincheck.php';
include 'dbcarsconfig.php';
include 'adminheader.php';

?>


    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <!-- session response-->
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['response'])){  ?>
                <div class="alert alert-<?= $_SESSION['res_type']; ?> alert-dismissible">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <?= $_SESSION['response'];   ?>
                </div>
                <?php } unset($_SESSION['response']);?>

                <?php
                 $query="SELECT * FROM cars";
                 $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
                 $stmt->execute();
                 $result=$stmt->get_result();
                 ?>
                <table class="table table-dark table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Thumbnail</th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Reg no</th>
                            <th>Make</th>
                            <th>Model</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <?php while($row=$result->fetch_Assoc()){?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="<?= $row['image1']?>" width="100" height="50"></td>
                            <td><?= $row['id']?></td>
                            <td><?= $row['carreg']?></td>
                            <td><?= $row['make']?></td>
                            <td><?= $row['model']?></td>
                            <td><?= $row['price']?></td>

                            <td><a href="managecars.php?edit=<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="badge badge-success p-2"> Edit/View</a></td>
                            <td><a href="actioncars.php?delete=<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="badge badge-danger p-2" onclick="return confirm('Please be sure if you want to delete this record as it can not be undone');"> Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form action="actioncars.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $id;  ?>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="carreg" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter car reg no" value="<?= $carreg; ?>" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="make" class="form-control" placeholder="Make of car" value="<?= $make; ?>" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="model" class="form-control" placeholder="Model" value="<?= $model; ?>" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" value="<?= $price; ?>" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" name="oldimage" value="<?= $image1;  ?>">
                        <input type="file" name="image1" class="custom-file">
                        <img src="<?= $image1; ?>" width="120" class="img-thumbnail">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php  if ($update==true){ ?>
                        <input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Update record">
                        <?php }  else { ?>
                        <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Add record">
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Open source html, what do you see?

Comment: My guess is that you have some error in php and it prevents displaying the rest of the code. Try to find log file on your server to see if there are any errors.